# Autodesk Forge Viewer DiffTool Exention Count is not matching with BIM 360 Compare Tool count

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are using Autodesk Forge Viewer with DiffTool Extension to show the model differences between two versions of BIM360 models. Everything working fine except the count showing for the items that are Added/Removed/Modified. For the same model, the BIM360 compare tool shows different numbers compared to the DiffTool Extension. So, we are stuck with these mismatched numbers, any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

[image: BIM 360 Differences]

[image: DiffTool Extension Differences]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, this issue is addressed and resolved. The comments below for future reference:

- ensure use the same model version urn
- ensure load model with SVF2 data

  ```
   const options = {
     env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2',
   //getAccessToken: fetchForgeToken
    accessToken: '<hard copy of token>'
   };
  ```
- ensure to specify the correct viewerable id (if not specified, viewer will load default 3D view, which might not be same to what are compared in BIM360).[image]

Comment: Thanks, Xiaodong for your support. Problem resolved.